# Spring programmatically register RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a working url as this: `localhost/info`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/info")
public class VersionController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody
   Map get() {
      loadProperties();
      Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
      m.put("buildTimestamp", properties.getProperty("Application-Build-Timestamp"));
      m.put("version", properties.getProperty("Application-Version"));
      return m;
   }

}
```

and I would to register some other mappings at initializing of my application as this:

```
localhost/xxxx/info
localhost/yyyy/info
localhost/zzzz/info
```

All these urls will return same response as `localhost/info`

The xxxx, yyyy part of the application is changeable. I have to register custom mappings as

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("???").setViewName("???");
}
```

Bu this is only working for views.

Any idea for dynamic registration?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use URLs of the form `/affId/1313/info`?

Comment: Yes because it was completely fictional. Actually the changing part is not id part. :(

Comment: describing a situation that bears no relationship to your actual problem doesn't help you, and wastes the time of anyone who tries to help you.

Comment: And if your current example isn't as completely fictional as your earlier example, @NilsH has given you a workable answer that should require less effort than registering a new `HandlerMapping`.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to learn programmatically registering beans as Costi Ciudatu has resolved perfectly. Anyway, thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register a new [HandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) where you can add the handlers for your URL paths; the most convenient implementation would be [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html).

If you want those handlers to be bean methods (like those annotated with `@RequestMapping`) you should define them as [HandlerMethod](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html) wrappers so that the already registered `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` will invoke them.

Comment: How to use `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`? How to define them as `HandlerMethod` wrappers? A little example would make this answer much better.

Comment: Be careful when you register your own Handler mapping. By default, the new handler ignores all HandlerInterceptor instances.

Answer (score 4):

As of Spring `5.0.M2`, Spring provides a functional web framework that allows you to create "controller"-like constructs programmatically.

What you would need to do in your case is create a proper [RouterFunction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/RouterFunction.html) for the URLs you need to handle, and then simply handle the request with the appropriate [HandlerFunction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/HandlerFunction.html).

Keep in mind however that these constructs are not part of Spring MVC, but part of Spring Reactive.

Check out [this](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/22/new-in-spring-5-functional-web-framework) blog post for more details

Comment: Is there any way to use `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`s somehow with functional endpoints?

Comment: Not that I am aware of

Answer (score 4):

I believe that simple example is worth more than 1000 words :) In SpringBoot it will look like...

Define your controller (example health endpoint):

```
public class HealthController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(@NotNull HttpServletRequest request, @NotNull HttpServletResponse response) {
        return new ModelAndView(new MappingJacksonSingleView(), "health", Health.up().build());
    }

}
```

And create your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomHealthConfig {

    @Bean
    public HealthController healthController() {
        return new HealthController();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2);
        mapping.setUrlMap(ImmutableMap.of("/health", healthController()));
        return mapping;
    }

}
```

Regarding the handler order - take a look about the reason here: [Java configuration of SimpleUrlHandlerMapping (Spring boot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037113/java-configuration-of-simpleurlhandlermapping-spring-boot)

The `MappingJacksonSingleView` is auxiliary class in order to return single json value for model and view:

```
public class MappingJacksonSingleView extends MappingJackson2JsonView {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected Object filterModel(Map<String, Object> model) {
        Object result = super.filterModel(model);
        if (!(result instanceof Map)) {
            return result;
        }

        Map map = (Map) result;
        if (map.size() == 1) {
            return map.values().toArray()[0];
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

Jackson single view source - this blog post: https://www.pascaldimassimo.com/2010/04/13/how-to-return-a-single-json-list-out-of-mappingjacksonjsonview/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible (now) to register request mapping by `RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerMapping()` method.

Example:

```java
@Autowired
RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

public void register(MyController myController) throws Exception {
    RequestMappingInfo mappingInfo = RequestMappingInfo.paths("xxxx/info").methods(RequestMethod.GET).build();
    Method method = myController.getClass().getMethod("info");
    requestMappingHandlerMapping.registerMapping(mappingInfo, myController, method);
}
```

Comment: can you explain it please?

Comment: Check out the documentation for the mentioned method for more details. Example I've posted just maps URL to an halndling method, nothing more. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#registerMapping-org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Method-

Answer (score 0):

You could register your own HandlerMapping by extending the [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html), e.g. override the `registerHandlerMethod`.

Answer (score -5):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve, but maybe you can use @PathVariable in your @RequestMapping, something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/affId/{id}")
public void myMethod(@PathVariable("id") String id) {}
```

Edit: Original example has changed it appears, but you might be able to use PathVariable anyway.