# Spring boot can I replace ResourceHttpRequestHandler with my own implementation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am running into [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7653) since I have an app that has restful services but I need to serve up some static ones too. In this app I also use the `EnableSwagger2` annotation. It looks like this class is public and I could subclass it but I am not sure how to configure that.  My goal is to override [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java#L324) so I can have control over 404s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I finally did do this and it worked successfully for me. The config got me for a bit but here it is. Say you subclass `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` with one named `CustomResourceHandler`.  In my `Application.java` this wired it up properly:

```
@Bean
public ResourceHttpRequestHandler resourceHttpRequestHandler() {
    ResourceHttpRequestHandler requestHandler = new CustomResourceHandler();
    requestHandler.setLocations(Arrays.<Resource>asList(applicationContext.getResource("/")));
    return requestHandler;
}

@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping sampleServletMapping(){
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2);
    Properties urlProperties = new Properties();
    urlProperties.put("/**", "resourceHttpRequestHandler");
    mapping.setMappings(urlProperties);
    return mapping;
}

@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

- This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037113/java-configuration-of-simpleurlhandlermapping-spring-boot) helped me with the proper config of the mapper.
- This [Answer about context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673230/spring-boot-overriding-favicon) helped me get the locations set properly in my handler. I was setting them a different way but it wasn't working 100% properly for all my resources

Comment: turns out if you want to run as JAR you need further mappings when you set locations to mimic defaultresourcehandler.